# UFT windows popup identification issue in windows locked remote machine

Tags: hp-uft

So I have been having a problem with running this UFT script using windows RDP session, I have a task scheduled in task scheduler to trigger this script. As I know the problem is that the application displays a windows popup message which UFT is NOT able to identify since the scripts are executing in the remote machine which is locked. But when I login to the remote machine and trigger the scripts or task manually it runs fine.

I have the object stored in the shared repository and this is the code I am using:

```
 Browser("Member Website").Dialog("Message from webpage").WinButton("OK").Click
```

I am using UFT 12.52 and the application is a webbased application running on Internet Explorer.

How can I make sure that UFT script is able to click the windows popup button when windows is locked?

[image: "Meesage from webpage" Image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QTP is Not able to Click on OK button of Window popup when the VM is minimised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814903/qtp-is-not-able-to-click-on-ok-button-of-window-popup-when-the-vm-is-minimised)

Comment: [Reference](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.02/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/RunYourTest_DisconnectedRDP.htm)